# Issues with Alerts in full-screen application

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to display an alert on top of another alert in a full-screen JavaFX application.  Without full-screen it works fine, the second alert is displayed on top of the first alert. With full-screen however the second alert is displayed under the first one despite having focus as shown in the first screenshot. Is it possible to have the second alert displayed on top?

[image]

Also as another issue regarding alerts in full-screen, when going to the desktop or alt+tab in Windows the alert is displayed despite setting the parent stage as owner as shown in the second screenshot (only the first alert for some reason). Is it possible to have the alerts tied to the full-screen parent stage so they aren't displayed when the parent stage isn't?

[image]

Example application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void run(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button button1 = new Button("CREATE 2 ALERTS");
        button1.setOnAction(event -> {
            createAlert("First alert", stage, 300, 300);
            createAlert("Second alert", stage, 500, 100);
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(button1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createAlert(String text, Stage parentStage, int width, int height) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText(text);
        alert.initOwner(parentStage);
        alert.getDialogPane().setPrefWidth(width);
        alert.getDialogPane().setPrefHeight(height);
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

The problem has been replicated with two Windows 10 v10.0 machines, with java v1.8.0_161 javafx v8.0.161 and java v16.0.1 javafx v16

Comment: I see the expected result on MacOS with JavaFX 8 or 16. For wider response, add imports and consider including system information, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjavafx%5d%20os.name).

Comment: JavaFX has various methods for controlling the z-order of windows, try them and see if they fix any of your issues.  [setAlwaysOnTop​](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)), [toFront](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#toFront()), [toBack](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#toBack()).  I use a Mac, not a Windows machine and, from trashgod's comment, behavior is fine on a Mac, so I can't replicate the issues myself.

Comment: The window ordering issue is a separate issue from hiding the child window when the parent fullscreen stage is not displayed, so it might be best to ask such things as separate questions in the future.  You can link to cross-reference the questions if needed.

Comment: I added imports and system information to the question. Seems to be a Windows-only bug then perhaps? Alerts/Dialogs are not Stages/Windows so I don't think they have any methods for controlling z-order? @jewelsea

Comment: You could get the stage or window associated with the Dialog by getting the scene, then the window from the dialog pane (e.g. `dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()`, you might need to do it via a listener or event to ensure that the it is initialized when you get it.

Answer (score 2):

After trying out the alwaysOnTop properties on the Alert Stages it seems there is some sort of bug that forces the first alert to be always on top even if the property is correctly false. This causes both the issues in the question.

Workaround that fixes both issues:

```java
stageAlert1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
stageAlert1.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
stageAlert2.toFront();
```

Example app fixed:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void run(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button button1 = new Button("CREATE 2 ALERTS");
        button1.setOnAction(event -> {
            Alert alert1 = createAlert("First alert", stage, 300, 300);
            Alert alert2 = createAlert("Second alert", stage, 500, 100);
            Stage stageAlert1 = (Stage)alert1.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
            Stage stageAlert2 = (Stage)alert2.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
            stageAlert1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            stageAlert1.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            stageAlert2.toFront();
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane(button1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Alert createAlert(String text, Stage parentStage, int width, int height) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText(text);
        alert.initOwner(parentStage);
        alert.getDialogPane().setPrefWidth(width);
        alert.getDialogPane().setPrefHeight(height);
        alert.show();
        return alert;
    }
}
```

Comment: smells like a bug - you might consider reporting it to get it fixed eventually :)